# What are "forward/backward" solutions to first order difference/differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, reference-request, terminology, economics

Recently, I've met for the first time with the so called "forward/backward" solutions to first order difference/differential equations. It seems that the subject goes back to Blanchard's "Backward and Forward Solutions for Economies with Rational Expectations" https://www.jstor.org/stable/1801627.

Is there some reference with simple examples for this type of calculations? Some textbook or lecture notes?

For example : If I have the differential equation $x' = ax + b$ with $a, b$ real constants I get the following "forward solution" :
$$
x(0) = \left(\frac{b}{a} + x(t)\right)e^{-at} - \frac{b}{a}
$$
and the following "backward solution" :
$$
x(0) = \left(\frac{b}{a} + x(-t)\right)e^{at} - \frac{b}{a}
$$

Is that correct?

I would appreciate any comments or references on the subject

Comment: You could also write $(ax(t_1)+b)e^{at_1}=(ax(t_2)+b)e^{at_2}$ to get a general formula. What you write are special cases solved for $x(0)$.

Comment: I see. Is $t_1 > t_2$ or the other way around? You know some textbook or a downloadable lecture notes on the subject?

Comment: It does not matter, this is true for any pair of time points.

Answer (score 1):

The Crux/Core of your Query is covered by the following Discussion :

A Differential Equation may be solved analytically to get Exact Solutions.
In some cases , the Exact Solutions are either (1) not Possible (theoretically no way to Derive it or Practically too cumbersome to Evaluate or ETC) or (2) not desirable (Discrete values may be wanted or the Solver is looking to get numerical values , not algebraic Equations or ETC)

In such Cases , the technique is to convert the given Differential Equation to a Difference Equation.
Basically , that technique is to substitute Differentials $dy/dx$ with Differences $\Delta y / \Delta x$.

Now , the Differences are (1) APPROXIMATE & (2) come in at least 3 **"flavours"** :

**(1)** Take "Next value of $x$" & "Current value of $x$" : $(n+1)(\Delta x)$ & $(n)(\Delta x)$
Thus we have :
$$dy/dx \approx \frac{[y((n+1)(\Delta x))-y((n)(\Delta x))]}{[\Delta x]} \tag{1}$$
Substitute this in the Differential Equation & solve it to get "forward" Solution.

**(2)** Take "Current value of $x$" & "Previous value of $x$" : $(n)(\Delta x)$ & $(n-)(\Delta x)$
Thus we have :
$$dy/dx \approx \frac{[y((n)(\Delta x))-y((n-1)(\Delta x))]}{[\Delta x]} \tag{2}$$
Substitute this in the Differential Equation & solve it to get "backward" Solution.

**(3)** Take "Next value of $x$" & "Previous value of $x$" : $(n+1)(\Delta x)$ & $(n-)(\Delta x)$
Thus we have :
$$dy/dx \approx \frac{[y((n+1)(\Delta x))-y((n-1)(\Delta x))]}{[2\Delta x]} \tag{3}$$
Substitute this in the Differential Equation & solve it to get "Central" Solution.

Now , Solutions (1) , (2) , (3) are APPROXIMATE Solutions which may not even match each other.

Here is 1 reference :
[http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~mjr/WebAppendices/Q-DiffEqs.pdf](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/%7Emjr/WebAppendices/Q-DiffEqs.pdf)
Image :
[image: Differential Difference]

Comment: Thanks. I'd heard of these methods in numerical integration. However, my question is more on the nature of mathematical economy problems where this terminology arises. In case of difference equations the idea is clear: a "backward solution" is simply obtained by repeated substitutions starting with $x_t = f(x_{t-1})$ and then going backward until the initial condition. You get the solution, but by "backward substitutions". Similarly for forward solutions. My question is, what does it mean to "backward" solve a differential equation as $x'(t) = ax(t) + b$, for instance?

Comment: We solve a Differential Equation by converting it to a Difference Equation , which can then be solved either forwards or backwards Depending which **"way"** we want to approximate the Differentials.